# spark --py-files is not working for zip made with python code but works with zip using mac

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, compression

I'm trying to use the flag `--py-files` with a zip file that include multiple python packages, since the machine that runs the spark can not pip install packages but it has access to S3.

The package I'm trying to use is `hvac` so first I tried everything locally.
I pip installed all of the packages that `hvac` uses (inda, certifi, urllib3, charset_normalizer, requests, pyhcl) went into my site packages choose the folders that were installed, compressed it using my mac (the fact that its mac is important) uploaded it to S3 and I could use the package `hvac`.

So later I tried to some of these steps using python, so I have the following code:

1. I pip install into a folder:
   `pip install -r python_spark/requirements.txt -t ./packages`
2. I go into the parent root of packages and run the function:

```
def zip_dirs() -> None:
    with zipfile.ZipFile('packages.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_STORED) as zip_file:
        for root, dir_name, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if not file == '.DS_Store':
                    zip_file.write(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file),
                                                                             os.path.join(path, '..')))
```

3. upload it to s3

but after doing the compression using python I try to run the spark again and I get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hvac'`
I know the issue is the compression since if I unzip it and zip it again using the right click `compress` option from my mac and I upload it, its working...

So I wonder what is the compression I need to do in order for it to work (tried using shutil and it is not working as well...)

Thanks!